# Can the sequence of successive digits of $\pi^{18}$ ever give a prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, pi, decimal-expansion

In this question

[First $k$ digits of $\pi^n$ and compositeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3580668/first-k-digits-of-pin-and-compositeness)

it is asked for some $\ n\ $ giving late or possible never a prime number. A good condidate is $\ n=18\ $. According to my calculations with PARI/GP, we do not get a prime after more than $\ 11\ 000$ digits. Note that the digits before the comma are used as well and we also do not arrive at a prime before reaching the comma.

> Is $\ \lfloor \pi^{18}\cdot 10^k \rfloor\ $ ever prime ?

Heuristically, we can expect that a prime will eventually occur , if we assume that the digits of $\ \pi^{18}\ $ behave like a pseudo-random-generator. Motivation for the $\ 18\ $ is that it is the first tough case (see the table in the answer).

Comment: What did I say ? The downvote is there :)

Comment: Is it clear that a (uniformly) randomly generated string yields a prime at some point with probability $1$?  Is there an expected density of primes produced in this way?

Comment: @lulu Even if clear if it´s random, primes are not, only in random models about them.

Comment: @lulu This has a point. Even, if the probability is not exactly as the 1/ln(n)-model predicts it is probably large enough to ensure that we must arrive at a prime eventually, if the digits are actually random. Since we have no reason to doubt that the digits of $\pi^{18}$ behave like a random-generator, I highly exect not only one prime, but infinite many. But the smallest could well be too large to be ever detected !

Comment: In the mean time, I passed $\ 14\ 000\ $ digits

Comment: Oh, I don't disagree that we expect primes.  If you try the simpler problem, wherein we draw a string of uniformly random $n$ digit numbers, it certainly appears that the prime number theorem gets us infinitely many primes (with probability $1$ at least). But in this case the dependence between the selections looks like it complicates things.

Comment: "probability 1 at least" ? Can we have more than "almost surely" ?

Comment: @lulu By the way, do you like to run a program on a fast computer or know someone that can do it ? I try to factor a 107-digit number which should take only 2-3 hours on a fast computer. Mine is very old and will take several days.

Comment: I know someone set up for things like that.  If you send me the number I'll give him a shout.

Comment: @lulu Enzo Creti is still banned and I didn't see Robert Frost as well as didgogns since a very long time. Dana Jacobsen is unfortunately busy with massive merit-calculations. Do you know someone else ?

Comment: I have someone I can ask, not sure what computing power he can access at the moment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105549/discussion-between-peter-and-lulu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \large \left \lfloor \pi ^{18} \cdot 10^{16718} \right \rfloor $ is a probable prime.

Pari/GP code:

```
\p 16800
ispseudoprime(floor(Pi^18*10^16718))
time = 1min, 22,156 ms.
%# = 1
```

Comment: I see, Peter already found it about an hour before I posted.